# Search results page

Tags: search, query

I have a search results page that seems to be working the way that I need it to.  The issue is that I cannot figure out how to remove or edit what I think is descriptive text about the item (test2).

Anyone know how to change this?

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided enough context. Which results page? Has the result page been modified in any way? What are the attribute of the document or item that you think is descriptive - test2? Title? What are the other attributes you have blacked out? What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: The search box is directly searching a list and the results page displays those results.  The blacked out information is the title of the list item with the address.  Each item that is listed during the search shows "test2".  SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Alright, but where do you see test2 in the list itself? Does each item have that value in a field?  And is this test2 value repeated for each item in the search results page?

Comment: I have reviewed the list and its not there, it only shows on the search results page.

Comment: Sounds like either the Search Results web part in the results page you are looking at has been modified or one of the Search Display Templates.  I would suggest you start with the web part configuration and go from there.